# Not able to create objects in Powershell for invoking a web service

Tags: web-services, powershell, ssl-certificate

This might be a silly question. Please forgive me if it is so.

My objective is to call a https web service developed in Java and Axis2 from powershell script.

Below is a sample web service which I created and I am not even able to invoke this via powershell.

**Web Service Method Implementation**

```
package com.webservice;

public class AreaOperations 
{
    public Area calculateArea(Dimension dimension)
    {
        Area area = new Area();
        area.setArea(dimension.getLength() * dimension.getBreadth());
        return area;
    }
}
```

**Soap Request**

```
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:web="http://webservice.com" xmlns:xsd="http://webservice.com/xsd">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <web:calculateArea>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <web:dimension>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <xsd:breadth>100</xsd:breadth>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <xsd:length>200</xsd:length>
         </web:dimension>
      </web:calculateArea>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I followed the stack exchange link [In Powershell to consume a Soap complexType to keep a Soap service hot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12516512/in-powershell-to-consume-a-soap-complextype-to-keep-a-soap-service-hot) to create the following power shell script

**PSScript**

```
$URI="http://localhost:8080/axis2/services/AreaOperations?wsdl"
$proxy=New-WebServiceProxy -uri $URI

#get autogenerated namespace
$type = $proxy.GetType().Namespace

#create the data type
$CalculateAreaRequestDT = ($type + '.calculateArea')
$DimensionDT = ($type + '.dimension')


#create objects
$areaRequest = new-object ($CalculateAreaRequestDT)
$dimension = new-object ($DimensionDT)

# Assign values
$dimension.length="200"
$dimension.width="100"

$areaRequest.dimension=$dimension

#Tada
$proxy.authenticateUser($areaRequest)
```

However I am getting the following error when I execute the line  ***$areaRequest = new-object ($CalculateAreaRequestDT)***

```
New-Object : Cannot find type [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewWebserviceProxy.AutogeneratedTypes.WebServiceProxy12_services_AreaOperations_wsdl.calculateArea]: make sure the assembly containing this type is loaded.
At line:1 char:26
+ $areaRequest = new-object <<<<  ($CalculateAreaRequestDT)
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidType: (:) [New-Object], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
```

Can you please help me resolve this issue.

Also we need to access the enterprise webservice using a P12 certificate, If some one shed the light on accessing these secured web service via powershell, it would be greatly helpful.

Note: Post edited to reflect the changes in our PROD environment as and also as per the Keith Hill's comment

Comment: Does it not work if you execute `$proxy.calculateArea(100.0, 200.0)`?

Comment: @KeithHill thanks for the reply. when I gave the the command `$proxy | gm` I am getting the following as the method signature: `System.Void calculateArea(float length, bool lengthSpecified, float width, bool widthSpecified, System.Double&, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089 return, System.Boolean&, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089 returnSpecified)`. I don't know how to call this method. So I am going to change my method signature and post the query again

Comment: guys, any reply will be useful